# Text gets truncated or hidden on a TextField on a macOS app

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a `TextField` on a `.sheet` that is acting up and I don't know why or how to solve it. When you type a long text, the cursor reaches the end of the `TextField` (the right end), and it stays there. You can continue to write (and the text will get entered) but you can't see it, nor scroll to it, nor move the cursor.

Is this a default behavior? If not, how do I fix it? What am I not doing right? I haven't found anything either here at SO, or on Apple's forums or various SwiftUI sites.

Here's how it looks

[image]

And here's the code for the view:

```
struct SheetViewNew: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var taskdata: DataModel
    
    @Binding var isVisible: Bool
    @Binding var enteredText: String
    @Binding var priority: Int
    var priorities = [0, 1, 2]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Enter a new task")
                .font(.headline)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)

            TextField("New task", text: $enteredText)
                 .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                 .font(.system(size: 14.0))
                 .onSubmit{
                     if enteredText == "" {
                         self.isVisible = false
                         return
                     }
                     taskdata.tasks.append(Task(id: UUID(), title: enteredText, priority: priority))
                 }
            
            Picker("Priority", selection: $priority) {
                Text("Today").tag(0)
                Text("Important").tag(1)
                Text("Normal").tag(2)
            }.pickerStyle(RadioGroupPickerStyle())
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                Button("Cancel") {
                    self.isVisible = false
                    self.enteredText = ""
                }
                .keyboardShortcut(.cancelAction)
                .buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button("Add Task") {
                    if enteredText == "" {
                        self.isVisible = false
                        return
                    }
                    taskdata.tasks.append(Task(id: UUID(), title: enteredText, priority: priority))
                    taskdata.sortList()
                    self.isVisible = false
                }
                .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
                .buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: This has been addressed here, although I don't have the link at my fingertips. Seems like a bug on Apple's part. My solution was to wrap `NSTextField`

Comment: Thank you. Everything I find about using NSTextField in swiftui is lines and lines of code... This is not looking good....

Comment: I’m pretty sure my version of it is < 100 lines. Maybe less than 50

Comment: 50 lines of code to solve this issue is less than ideal... I wonder if next version of Swiftui will have a fix...

Comment: Of course it’s less than ideal — having no bugs would be ideal. But it’s also easily actionable.

Comment: True. Thanks. Any chance to share that code?

Comment: There's some extra stuff in here you likely don't need. This is just directly what is in my app: https://gist.github.com/jnpdx/b016362925b8cadcecf7dde6f0e64f5d